# Windows 10 cannot connect to windows 7 computers

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, smb, netbios

Newly installed (by full reset) Windows 10 Pro computer cannot connect to Windows 7 computers and Debian SMB servers on the network.

It can see all computers and servers on the network (all computers have same workgroup name), but can connect only to others Windows 10 computers.

I enabled "SMB 1.0/CIFS Client" in Windows features. "Enable NetBIOS over TCP/IP" is checked.

If i do from cmd:

```
nbtstat -a myservername
```

it works and shows server information

```
Ethernet:
Node IpAddress: [192.168.0.32] Scope Id: []

       NetBIOS Remote Machine Name Table

   Name               Type         Status
---------------------------------------------
MYSERVERNAME   <00>  UNIQUE      Registered
MYSERVERNAME   <03>  UNIQUE      Registered
MYSERVERNAME   <20>  UNIQUE      Registered
☺☻__MSBROWSE__☻<01>  GROUP       Registered
MYDOMAIN       <00>  GROUP       Registered
MYDOMAIN       <1D>  UNIQUE      Registered
MYDOMAIN       <1E>  GROUP       Registered

MAC Address = 00-00-00-00-00-00
```

but

```
net view \\myservername
```

gives error *"System error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found."*

Comment: Are user accounts and their passwords sync?

Comment: Can you use Wireshark to capture the failed connection attempts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to user **gravity** comment, i used Wireshark.
In Wireshark there was "SMB2 Negotiate protocol", then "SMB2 Session setup", 
there Windows 10 was stopping connection after server offered him to connect using Guest access.

So i found this Microsoft article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4046019

Turning `"Enable insecure guest logons"` in group policy resolved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this solution and want to get it out there.

Update KB4480970 deactivates the Network Controller on Windows 7 and Server 2008 systems such that shares at a server are no longer accessible.

So uninstall *Microsoft Update KB4480970* with this command:

```
wusa.exe /uninstall /KB:4480970
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Network and Sharing Centre -> Advance sharing settings -> All Networks -> Enable file sharing for devices that use 40- or 56-bit encrypting
Reboot

Also can you connect via IP instead of netBIOS? any 3rd party antivirus?

Comment: Keeping it simple, just the IP address. If we can't connect to that then not a netBIOS issue.

Comment: With IP is exactly the same - `nbtstat` works and `net view` - not.

Comment: Turning `"Enable file sharing for devices that use 40- or 56-bit encrypting"` did not resolved given issue.